# Riverpod: How to read provider after async gap

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am trying to build a simple login screen. For this I have set up a `StateProvider` to indicate whether to show a loading indicator:

```
final loginIsLoadingProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);
```

When a button is pressed I call the following function:

```
void logInUser(WidgetRef ref) async {
    ref.read(loginIsLoadingProvider.notifier).state = true;
    await Future.delayed(1.seconds); //login logic etc.
    ref.read(loginIsLoadingProvider.notifier).state = false; //Exception
return;
```

But calling `ref.read(...)` after awaiting the future throws the following exception:

> FlutterError (Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable. To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.)

Why cant I call `ref.read()` after an async gap? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I found that adding a `scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();` to the scaffold fixes this, but I feel like this should not be necessary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution is to read your providers *before* the async gap, but not use them immediately.

For example:

```dart
Future<void> logInUser(WidgetRef ref) async {
  final isLoadingNotifier = ref.read(loginIsLoadingProvider.notifier);
  isLoadingNotifier.state = true;

  await someAsyncOperation();

  isLoadingNotifier.state = false;
}
```